# Trouble with ActiveX Reverseengineering (DispCallFunc Trick does not work)

Tags: debugging, com

It is common to set a breakpoint on `oleaut32!DispCallFunc` to catch the function call to the ActiveX component and it worked for me until recently. I tried to reverse engineer a ActiveX component I got from some web file storage site and IE does not stop on `DispCallFunc`. Any other tricks to catch function call to ActiveX ?

Comment: Seems it is programmed in MFC

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `!activex` command in Immunity debugger to list and set breakpoints.

Comment: It does not seem to working. It fails to find ActiveX functions and print "ActiveX Methods Trapped"

Comment: I've just verified the source code of the command (it's python in pycommands folder, the filename is the same as the command), the return value is normal, did you use these command ("!activex <name of Control>                          -    this outputs all functions and their addresses.", "!activex <name of Control> break <function name>    -    set a breakpoint on a function name.") to inspect and break on your module, this is extracted from the usage message.

Comment: Yest I used that command but it outputs "ActiveX Methods Trapped" message and no breakpoints are set :(